# How to enable more than 2 finger support in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, touch

I'm currently building a web interface that will be used in kiosk mode on Chrome for a very large touch screen running Windows 7. This screen has six touch points and I would like to use them. (All six points are known to be working.)

I've tried a variety of jQuery plugins ([TouchSwipe](http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html), [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/), etc) to show proof of concept, however while stating to support more than two fingers, none seem to work in Chrome past two points.

Using TouchSwipe, I've added the following code to my page:

```
$('body').swipe({
    swipe: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
        console.log('Swiped '+direction+' with '+fingers+' finger(s).');
    },
    threshold: 0,
    fingers: 'all'
});
```

This works, and logs in the console a one-finger and two-finger swipe. However, if I swipe with any more than two fingers, it always registers as only two fingers have swiped. (Run this same test on an iPad, for example, it it correctly will show 3 or 4 fingers.)

I cannot find any information stating how many simultaneous touch points Chrome (or any other browser) supports. Is it possible to instruct Chrome to listen to more than two simultaneous touch points with JavaScript (or some other means)? How?

Comment: Chrome seems to have an issue with certain hardware.. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=326022%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=326022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered our problem. It was very localized, so I am going to also recommend this question be closed.

The software we were using to test the 6 touch points was working, however a Windows driver was failing to load on boot, therefore only 2 points were available. Once the driver was properly initialized, all 6 points work in Chrome.

Comment: What were the drivers? Also what was the device you used for this? I'm currently working with a device that has 46 touch point support, but can't get past 10 simultaneous touches. Any help would be awesome! Thanks.